# javascript crashing iPad browser

Tags: javascript, ipad, crash, carousel

I have some javascript inside a function that creates and populates an image carousel. It works fine after activating it in a pop up window the first 5 or 6 times, but then it eventually crashes the browser.  I think there's some kind of leak, like something inside of it needs to be deleted before it gets created again.  I know it's the carousel because if I get rid of that part of the script, it no longer crashes.

Here's the carousel script:

```
/* carousel */

var carousel,
el,
i,
page,
slides;

carousel = new SwipeView('#wrapper', {
                         numberOfPages: slides.length,
                         hastyPageFlip: true
                         });

// Load initial data
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    page = i==0 ? slides.length-1 : i-1;

    el = document.createElement('span');
    el.innerHTML = slides[page];
    carousel.masterPages[i].appendChild(el)
}

carousel.onFlip(function () {
                var el,
                upcoming,
                i;

    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        upcoming = carousel.masterPages[i].dataset.upcomingPageIndex;

        if (upcoming != carousel.masterPages[i].dataset.pageIndex) {
            el = carousel.masterPages[i].querySelector('span');
            el.innerHTML = slides[upcoming];
        }
    }
});
```

This script runs every time I click a link that launches a floating window.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I needed to clear my wrapper div. In the beginning of my function call:

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = "";
```

Seems to work.